# Dense property of intersection of Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm using Muscalu and Schlag's textbook (online notes) to study Littlewood-Paley theory in harmonic analysis, where I encounter the following claim:

Pick an arbitrary real number $s$, we have that the intersection of $\cap_{t \in \mathbb{R}}H^{t}$ is dense in $H^{s}$.

The author mentioned that it suffices to prove the following equivalence of norms:

$$c^{-1}\|f-P_{\leq k}f\|_{H^{s}}^2 \leq \sum_{l \geq k}2^{2ls}\|P_{l}f\|_{L^2}^{2} \leq c\|f-P_{\leq k}f\|_{H^{s}}^2 \quad (\forall \ f \in H^s)$$

where $c = c(s) > 0$ above is some constant dependent on $s$ and $P_{\leq k} = \sum_{j \leq k}P_{j}$ is the sum of a subset of Littlewood-Paley projection operators.

I can see how the dense property can be derived from the equivalence of norms exhibited above. However, I have tried using several properties of the Littlewood-Paley projection operators, but none of them helps me gain any progress in showing the inequality above...any hint/idea?

Comment: What kind of domain are we using here?  Is it not enough in context to note that $C^\infty_c$ is contained in all of them?

Comment: Isn't this almost by definition? Where exactly are you stuck? You have $f - P_{\leq k f} = P_{>k} f + (P_k + P_{k-1})(f - P_{\leq k} f)$. Then you just use almost orthogonality.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is special case of a simple general result (simple in that it follows easily from the spectral theorem).  Let $A$ be positive s.a. operator (we  can assume that it is bounded below by the identity operator).  Then it defines in a natural way a scale $H^t$ of Sobolev  spaces (for $t>0$, $H^t$ is the domain of definition of $A^t$).  Then $\bigcap H^t$ is dense in each component.  The classical Sobolev spaces are generated in this way by the Laplace operator on $n$-space and various s.a. differential operators (Laplace-Beltrami, Schrödinger) of physics supply variants.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Littlewood-Paley theory and Dense property of Sobolev spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393361/littlewood-paley-theory-and-dense-property-of-sobolev-spaces)

Comment: Yeah it does! Thank you so much!